# unterminated string literal error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have placed the below code inside of the  tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-includes/js/thickbox.js"></script>');    
    });
</script>
```

I got an error of "unterminated string literal".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is coming from the fact that your code includes `</script>` in it. This is causing the browser to think that you're terminating your `<script>` tag early. If you change your code to the following, it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="../wp-includes/js/thickbox.js"></' + 'script>');    
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, the above code breaks the `</script>` in your string into `'</' + 'script>'`, so that the browser doesn't parse it as a closing tag.

Comment: Yes my dear friend, there is no error but still I couldn't add thickbox.js to the head tag

Comment: @balaji why don't you use getscript of jquery ,it will take care of everything for you

Comment: yea, using getscript is probably the better way to go :-)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't have an unterminated string literal. The error means that you've started a string with a single or double quote, but don't have a second quote of the same kind to close the string.

Comment: @gov: No, they are not (in this context). You can have either `"text"` or `'text'` but not `"text'` or `'text"`. You cannot mix them.

Comment: @Felix i agree with you , you cannot have 'test" for sure

Answer (score 1):

"unterminated string literal error" is not a Javascript error.

It hints towards a PHP script error, though. Post that code and you shall receive help.

Answer (score 0):

Balaji ,

Use jquery' getscript , its very nice way of doing it , it will append in head section and less changes of errors

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/
```