# jquery append a lot of html (getting "unterminated string literal" or "bad escape" error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm trying to use javascript/jquery to dynamically add to a form based on responses to previous elements. However, I keep getting an "unterminated string literal" error. When looking at it with colour-coding/highlighting, it looks fine…

Originally I had everything on one line (no escapes), and I got a `unterminated string literal` error, so I tried escaping new lines, and I got a `bad escape` error.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/8PTbL/

btw, I looked thru a bunch of older posts, but just found questions from people asking about HEREDOC (which I had looked up previously).

Comment: your jquery code has syntax errors. Did you try testing each line of code if its working. Remove all your code, and see if its coding

Comment: answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4417801/758177

Answer (score 4):

Where is `qArray` and `counter_oneChoice` defined?

You'll need to break up the script tags like so:

```
'<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript"> \
 $(\'input[name="'+id+'"]\').change( 
     function(){ counter_oneChoice(qArray, 40); 
 }); \
 </scr' + 'ipt>');'
```

Otherwise, your jslint errors might just be shortcomings in the linter because of the odd formlation of the code. This is a pretty messed up what to do it.

Comment: qArray and counter_oneChoice are defined elsewhere. qArray is just an array of booleans.

Comment: This was one problem. however, IE8 won't append `<div id="'+id+'" style="display:none;"><ul><li>In the <span class="highlight">past 12 months</span>, how often did you use <span class="highlight">'`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

This is more a remark than an answer but here is a an efficient and readable way to insert *big* amount of html at once:

- make an array
- push your markup into the array as strings
- join and append

Example:

```
var id = 0, drug = 'hello', html = [];

html.push('<ul id="' + id + '">');
html.push('<li>In the <span class="highlight">past 12 months</span>, how often did you use <span class="highlight">' + drug + '?</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="0" />Never</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="0" />More than once a day</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="0" />Once a day</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="0" />More than once a week</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="0" />Once a week<</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="0" />More than once a month</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="0" />Once a month</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="7" />Less than once a month</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="77" />I prefer not to answer</li>');
html.push('<li><input name="' + id + '" type="radio" value="99" />Don\'t know</li>');
html.push('</ul>');
$("body").append(html.join(''));
```

Comment: oow, creative (fyi I think it wouldn't fix the issue where the browser interperates `'<script…`, but the `scr'+'ipt` fix could be used with your array idea).

Comment: You're right, but i thought it was worth mentioning it and it would'nt have fit in a comment :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="niu12"]').change(function() {
    alert("changed");


   $('input[name="niu12"][type="radio"]').removeAttr("checked");
                    var id = this.value;
                    var drug = $(this).attr("title");
                    $("#nidu_fq").append('<ul id="'+id+'"> \
                            <li>In the past 12 months</span>, how often did you use <span  class="highlight">'+drug+'</li> </ul>');


}); // done
```

This works - just keep adding line by line to this.

Answer (score 0):

modified the code a bit. I get errors that some functions are missing.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8PTbL/13/)

Comment: checking checkboxes isn't producing any results :/

Comment: @Jacob. There were some syntax errors. Updated the code