# Insert javascript to a specific div using google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I currently implement iframe code using Google Tag - Custom HTML to a specific div (id="empty-div") on my target page using the below code and it works just fine. Google Tag manager (Custom Html tag + Trigger)

Custom HTML tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('[id="empty-div"]').html('<iframe src="https://feed.mikle.com/widget/v2/115010/" height="1200px" width="100%" class="fw-iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
</script>
```

I want to replace the iframe code above with the below provided code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://feed.mikle.com/js/fw-loader.js" data-fw-param="115010/"></script>
```

Looking for a simple implementation

Doing the below causes errors when publishing in Google Tag Manager

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('[id="empty-div"]').html('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://feed.mikle.com/js/fw-loader.js" data-fw-param="115010/"></script>');
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is wrong with the second code block?

Comment: The second block code is to be used in place of the iframe code that is in the above script. Just replacing it causes errors. Top code is how I add the iframe to the specific div with id = empty-div using GTM. I want to add the bottom javascript to the specific div using GTM

Comment: Could you please expand on what errors you are encountering and the motivation to switch over to the new implementation.

Comment: Also the method you used to implement the new script.

Comment: If I replace <iframe src....> .... </iframe> in the top code example and replace with the entire second code snippet I am publishing this via Google tag manager  and get a Tag manager publishing error: JavaScript compiler error - Error at line 3, character 37: Parse error. Unterminated string literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked up what caused the error.

> Parse error. Unterminated string literal

In Gtag you are adding a script that adds a script. When you upload your code it will become one big line of text. And that text opens with `<script>` and closes with `</script>`. In HTML this would all go right, but since it is a `string` the script tag will get closed off too early because there is another `</script>` tag in the middle that closes of the first tag. Leaving all code that follows it to be unparseable and will throw an error.

So I suggest that you use this script below which will use vanilla JavaScript to create a new `<script>` element, set the correct `src` and puts it inside the `<div id="empty-div">`. I've chosen to do it without `jQuery` since I find it easier to explain what happens without it. And it makes no difference for performance or other JavaScript at all.

I don't get the reason why you would append the `<script>` in a div, since that is not common practice and will not make a difference whatsoever on the `<div id="empty-div">`, but I'm sure you have your reasons.

```
<script>
  (function () {
    var empty = document.getElementById('empty-div');    // Select empty div
    var script = document.createElement('script');       // Create new script element
    script.setAttribute('data-fw-param', '115010');      // Add the data-fw-param attribute
    script.async = true;                                 // Set async to true. This can improve performance
    script.src = https://feed.mikle.com/js/fw-loader.js; // Set the src to the script
    empty.appendChild(script);                           // Insert the script into the empty div
  }())
</script>
```

I've found the explanation for the problem in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417749/unterminated-string-literal-error). Please for future reference search the error that a browser or tool is giving you. You'll have more chance of finding your answer, and faster!

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much, not only for your answer and explanation but your patience and persistence.